# QML: onClicked method on MouseArea of Rectangle is not getting invoked

Tags: qt, qml

I am new to Qt/QML. I am learning from [QML book](https://qmlbook.github.io/en/ch06/index.html#animating-added-and-removed-items), I am trying an example to add / remove an element to simple ListModel. After clicking "Add Item", **onClicked** method in **MouseArea** of **Rectangle** is not getting invoked. OnClicked method of delete is in delegation component is working fine.

Here is the code

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 480
    height: 300
    title: qsTr("Add / Remove")
    color: "blue"

    //ListModel
    ListModel{
        id: lmodel
        ListElement {number: 0}
        ListElement {number: 1}
        ListElement {number: 2}
        ListElement {number: 3}
        ListElement {number: 4}
        ListElement {number: 5}
    }

    // Add button
    Rectangle{
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.margins: 20
        height: 40
        color: "#00ff00"
        border.color: Qt.lighter(color, 1.1)

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "Add Item"
        }

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent // Edit1
            onClicked: { // this Method is not getting called
                console.log(" add clicked");
                lmodel.append({"number": ++parent.count});
            }
        }

        property int count: 5
    }

    //GridView
    GridView{
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        clip: true
        model: lmodel

        cellHeight: 45
        cellWidth: 45
        delegate: del

    }

    //delegate
    Component{
        id: del
        Rectangle{
            id: wrapper
            width: 40
            height: 40
            color: "yellow"
            Text {
                text: number
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    console.log(" num clicked");
                    lmodel.remove(index);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are anchoring `MouseArea` to `ListModel`

```
anchors.fill: lmodel
```

Second problem: `GridView` overlaps `MouseArea`. Try to disable it (just to ensure)

```
GridView{
    enabled: false
```

Comment: anchors.fill: parent is not working too. I have updated the code.